# Mysql PHP Arbitrary Increment

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I'm trying to increment +1 impression every time an ad is displayed on my site, however the variable increments +2 to +3 arbitrarily. I've removed everything that's working correctly and I made a page with only this code in it:

```
<?php
require "connect_to_mydb.php";
echo 'Hello***** '.$testVariable=$testVariable+1;
mysql_query("UPDATE `imageAds` SET `test`=`test`+1 WHERE `id`='1'");
?>
```

Every time the page is refreshed the, `test` increments arbitrarily either +2 or +3 and my page displays `Hello***** 1` (Just to show its not looping).  Access is restricted to this page so it's not other users refreshing the page.

Also, `id` and `test` are `int(11)` in the DB.

My DB required connection has nothing in it that would interfere.

**Edit**

Here is an updated code:

```
<?php
require "connect_to_mydb.php";
mysql_query("UPDATE `imageAds` SET `test`=`test`+1 WHERE `id`='1'");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imageAds WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1");
$check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($check > 0){ 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    echo $row['test'];
}
?>
```

Increments by +2 everytime

**Edit**
This is whats in connect_to_mydb.php

```
<?php  
$db_host = "*************************"; 

$db_username = "*********";  

$db_pass = "**********";  

$db_name = "**************";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to   mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");              
?>
```

Comment: Your test code doesn't display the value of `test`, so how do you know how much it's incrementing by?

Comment: Can you check that when you refresh the page only 1 http request is being sent.

Comment: You should modify your PHP code to `SELECT` and `echo` the value of `test` before and after the `UPDATE`.

Comment: I will modify it but that's how it was before.

Comment: Please post the code for `connect_to_mydb.php`. You can replace the security sensitive information with `*****` if you wish.

Comment: Okay, I think the culprit is Google Chrome! If someone can verify this, I put that exact code in a webpage, reloaded it with Google Chrome and it increments +2 and sometimes +3 times. Did it with Firefox, IE, and Safari and it increments +1 like its suppose to.  Is Google Chrome double loading pages? I know this a radical answer but can someone duplicate it? I have Chrome Version 18.0.1025.162.  Also, I tried it on my android browser and it does the +2 increment as well.

Comment: I think this is the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This +2/+3 error is occurring only with Chrome and my Mobile Android browser and the code is solid.  I looked to see if there is any issue with Chrome sending more than one http request (thx user1058351) and there is which is documented here:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402

So since this way was unreliable I just completed a work around that is solid.  Instead of including a PHP file that updates the amount of ad impressions on reload, I now have it so when the page loads, an AJAX request is sent to a separate PHP file which updates the ad stats and returns the appropriate data.  The key I think is to send it through the JS code so only one http request can be sent to increment the data.

Thank you to all who responded especially user1058351 and Mark Byers (not a bug in MYSQL but possibly appears to be a bug in Chrome).

Answer (score 3):

Either there's a bug in MySQL's implementation of UPDATE, or you're doing something wrong in some code you haven't posted.

Hint: It's *very* unlikely to be a bug in MySQL. Other people would have noticed it.

---

From what you've shown, it looks like your page is being loaded multiple times.

This attempt to prove that the code is only being called once doesn't prove anything:

```
echo 'Hello***** '.$testVariable=$testVariable+1;
```

This will always print the same thing (`Hello***** 1`) even if you open this page multiple times because the value of `$testVariable` is not preserved across seperate requests.

Comment: It depends what require "connect_to_mydb.php"; is doing. It might have  $testVariable defined global.